# To date and from date in magento admin

Tags: date

A simple question because google didn't help: In magento admin (coupons, price rules etc.) the "from date" and "to date" fields start at 00:01 that day and end at 23:59 on end date (dates are inclusive?)?

Thanks!

Comment: Not too sure what you mean. You want to know if the date you send start at 00:01 and ends at 23:59?

Comment: @Sander yes, the exact minute when it starts and if it is inclusive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of Magento versions back I checked this for the Shopping cart promo rules and seem to remember they used `=>` and `<=` in the query.

But in which file etc I can't remember anymore

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Magento 2 handles these fields as inclusive.